# how to call id using useEffect and how to load data in dropdown ? based on dropdown option changing it will load & fetch the data from api

Tags: node.js, reactjs

could you please help me how to load the data based on dropdown options changing. one dropdown contains category and another one contains products list. if i select one category it will load that products under based on that category.

```
useEffect(() => { 
    const getcategory = async () => { 
      try{ 
          const res = await fetch("``http://localhost:5000/PortfolioGroup``");
          if (!res.ok) throw Error('Did not receive expected data')//return await res.json();  
          const getdata = await res.json();   
          setCategory(getdata);
          console.log(getdata);
          setFetchError(null);
        } catch (err) {
           setFetchError(err.message);
        }
      }
      const getproductlist = async (portfolioId) => {
            try{
                   const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/manasa");
                   if (!res.ok) throw Error('Did not receive expected data');
                   //return await res.json();
                   const getdata = await res.json();
                   setCategory(getdata);
                   console.log(getdata);
                   setFetchError(null);
            } catch (err) {
                  setFetchError(err.message);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(() => getcategory(), 2000);
        setTimeout(() => getproductlist(), 2000);
        getproductlist();
      },[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

call the getcategory method on componentDidMount or

```
useEffect(() => {getcategory()}, [])
```

Now you have to call getproductlist whenever your category value changes so put a useEffect and category value in dependency array  as shown below.

```
    useEffect(() => {
       if(category) {
        getproductlist(category.portfolioId)
    } else {
       setProductList([])
    }
}, [category])
```